# Can I use webrtc in TideSDK?

Tags: html, webrtc, tidesdk, getusermedia

I want to use latest HTML5 features in my Tidesdk app like getusermedia, webrtc etc for screen sharing and sip calling? can anyone help regarding this? or any idea how can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no". WebRTC itself is pretty new and parts of it are still evolving. Although getUserMedia has been around the longest, TideSDK uses a very old version of Webkit. As such, many of the new "toys" are unavailable. You will see that a call to navigator.getUserMedia returns undefined.

Comment: Thanks @david for you suggestion, do you have any idea how can I implement screen share in tidesdk? any help will be appreciated

Comment: I think it's simply not possible at the moment. The only thing I can think of is doing some Flash/Flex/AS3 and embed that in TideSDK as a shell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Tikesdk but, for screen sharing I'd recommend a tool like [Screen Leap](http://www.screenleap.com/).  Screen sharing with webRTC is still very new and unless you have very tech savy user's they will not be able to use it.